# Button not enabling another control - life cycle issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I hope I can explain this well without having to post scads of source.

I have a page in an online store that lets the user pick a date for a tour.  That page has a ConLib which contains a couple of panels.  The first is:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_Grid" runat="server">
        <cb:SortedGridView ID="VariantGrid" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
            SkinID="PagedList" DataKeyNames="OptionList">
            <Columns>
            </Columns>
        </cb:SortedGridView>
    </asp:Panel>
```

and then another asp:Panel with other stuff - calendar, buttons, etc.  The SortedGridView is supplied by our shopping cart provider and is basically a regular asp:Grid.

When the user says they want 3 tickets I do a

```
pnl_Grid.Enabled="false"
```

to keep them from changing it after picking a date/time.  At various points they can click a reset button that will do many things but one task is to set the value to zero in the gridrow text boxes and enable the Grid since they reset the process and want to pick new things.

I have stepped through the code with breakpoints in place and it seems that the problem I am having is that my reset button click event handler fires after the Grid is rendered with the disabled status in the Page Render stage of life.  If that is true then setting the Grid in code behind will never show the enabled grid on the page without a refresh since it's already rendered.  If I refresh the page manually it does indeed show as enabled so I think I'm on the right problem.

My question is twofold, if there is enough info here to answer it:
1. Is it likely that what I think I am seeing is true - the page renders the control disabled and then the button handler tries to enable it but it's too late at that point since the control is already rendered?
2. How can I work around this?  I would prefer to avoid JQuery if at all possible... it has some unintended side effects with the way our original store software is written.

Further info:
I have a status flag _EventSelected which tells if the calendar event has been selected.  On the reset button click I set that to false and on PreRender I check that to see if it is false and enable the Grid.  Again, the status doesn't change until the Reset Button Click event handler and that is *after* the PreRender.

Thanks for your input!  I swear, some days ASP.NET makes perfect sense to me and other days it is clear as mud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution.  To force the page to refresh after the button enables the Grid, which is not displayed without the refresh, I added this to the btn_Reset_Click handler, found by searching for "cause page reload":

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), false);
```

It's not a bad solution since I'm in a reset / start-over state anyway.  Thanks for taking time to read my question!  Hopefully this will help someone else some day.